# How do I use custom actions in Payum?

Tags: php, symfony, action, symfony-2.3, payum

I have 2 versions of the same payment type I am writing plugins for and I need help understanding the difference in the architecture and how to handle the differences with **custom actions**.

**Method 1** is an *offsite* payment that returns to the '**done**' url, which in turn checks the status and redirects the user to a success/error page. (*When the user returns, MY SYSTEM sends a query  about the payment status*)

**Method 2** is again an *offsite* payment, however the user cannot be returned to the same '**done**' page as this payment gateway sends an individual notification to a url that I set when creating the payment, that contains the payment result data. So presently I send my user to a pending page. However I cannot use the '**done**' page to handle the separate notification as I need to set a different response (*Just 'OK', nothing else*) and the 'done' page wants to redirect as it it has been accessed by a user in the browser.

What is the best way to handle this? I have already written code to handle method 1 but need it to handle method 2 also.

**Can I use custom actions to achieve this?**

The docs aren't really that clear about how I can perform the seperate actions from the '**done**' url?

Thanks in advance

J

Comment: The done action is your project area, you can put there what ever you want there. 

About two payment methods: I believe you have to have two payment objects with different set of Payum's actions. It is a general approach.

Comment: Yeah. I have that. I guess my question is more directed at how do I actually create the action, how do i register it and then how do I use it in my 'done' action.

I find the documentation lacking detail and confusing. The action about custom actions doesn't really explain it to me.